# How to set up Postgres database for local Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I recently got a new machine and would now like to work on my projects from Github. I'm curious as to how to properly set up the Postgres database on my local machine. I have `postgresql`, `pgadmin3` and `libpq-dev` installed on Ubuntu (12.04).

I pull down the project:

`git clone https://github.com/thebenedict/cowsnhills.git`

and run:

`bundle`.

When I run:

`rake db:create && rake db:schema:load`

I get this error:

```
rake db:create && rake db:schema:load
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "cnh"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "cnh"
....
```

The `config/database.yml` file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_development
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: cnh

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_test
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: cnh

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_production
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: cnh
```

What's the proper way to set up the Postgres database so I can run this project on my local machine?

Right now when I start the Rails server I get:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

firstly, install postgresql

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update

#now install postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 libpq-dev
```

create a new user in psql

```
sudo su postgres
createuser user_name #Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

bundle install

development.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: user_name
  password:
```

Comment: I also had to `create database app_development owner user_name;` and then `alter user_name password 'password';`

Comment: no need to do it that way. use rake db:create, rake db:migrate . u can simply do rake db:setup to create and migrate.

Comment: execute createuser with `-W` to force a password prompt `createuser -s -W user_name`. Otherwise it may not ask you for one und you will have to set it afterwards with the `ALTER`-Statement

Answer (score 54):

I came across your question when looking for the same answer. I attempted to follow the instructions @prasad.surase gave you. The problem I found is the ppa repository is going to depreciate soon on 12.04 LTS. Instead I found this link and it really helped.

[PostgreSQL setup for Rails development in Ubuntu 12.04](http://linuxrails.blogspot.com/2012/06/postgresql-setup-for-rails-development.html)

1. Install postgresql and admin tools through the package manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev phppgadmin pgadmin3
   ```
2. Login to postgresql prompt as the postgres user

   ```
   sudo su postgres -c psql
   ```
3. Create a postgresql user for your project

   ```
   create user username with password 'password';
   ```
4. Setup your postgres user with the same name and password as your Ubuntu user and make him a postgres superuser

   ```
   alter user username superuser;
   ```
5. Create the development and test databases

   ```
   create database projectname_development;
   create database projectname_test;
   ```
6. Give permissions to the user on the databases

   ```
   grant all privileges on database projectname_development to username;
   grant all privileges on database projectname_test to username;
   ```

To end the postgresql session type `\q`

Update password for the user

```
alter user username with password ‘new password’;
```

Answer (score 2):

You follow this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/

to create a postgres user and replace the credentials in database.yml